# Does the expansion of the space affect the entanglements of particle pairs within the space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, space-expansion, quantum-entanglement, space

L.Susskind said about entanglements of particles that they are similar to corsets in that the entanglements play a role in helping the space retain its geometric structure, 
and to cause pairs of particles to lose their correlation would mean the space between them would deviate from its lowest possible energy state.

Does that also mean the entanglements can be affected by the changes in the structure of the space?

For example, If two entangled particles are placed in a hypothetical universe where those two particles were the only matter and that universe would then expand, would that 'weaken' the entanglement between the particles?

The analogy mentioned here comes from this video.
https://youtu.be/WFi9QYnqiYw?t=33m46s